# Enabling pinch zoom on iOS when using iScroll.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, zooming, iscroll

I'm building a one page scrollable web application using [iScroll.js](http://iscrolljs.com/) and I can't get its built in zoom feature to work no matter what I do. I'm including the iscroll-zoom.js file yet still haven't had any success.

I've got this in the head of my file:

```
<script src="js/iscroll.js"></script>
<script src="js/iscroll-zoom.js"></script>
<script src="js/iscroll-probe.js"></script>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">
```

And this script:

```
function loaded () {
myScroll = new IScroll('#wrapper', { 
    mouseWheel: true,
    zoom: true,
    bounce: false 
});
```

According to the [iScroll Documentation](http://iscrolljs.com/#zoom) this should work, but it doesn't. If it helps, I need to get this running on an iPad.

Comment: Have you fulfilled the CSS requirements? "Add position:relative or absolute to the scroll container (the wrapper). That alone usually solves most of the problems with wrongly calculated wrapper dimensions."

Comment: I have indeed, here's the code: 

  `#wrapper {
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 1;
 top: 0px;
 bottom: 0px;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 overflow: hidden;
   }`

Answer (score 0):

```
function createZoomForID (id) {
    $timeout(function(){
        var wrapper = document.getElementById(id);
        var myScroll = new IScrollZ(wrapper, {
            zoom: true,
            zoomMin: 1,
            zoomMax: 4,
            scrollX: true,
            scrollY: true,
            mouseWheel: true,
            freeScroll: true,
            wheelAction: 'zoom',
        });
        $scope[id] = myScroll;
    }, 125);
}
```